# Interesting algorithm task - elevator

Tags: algorithm

Its similar to knapsack problem but more complex.

There is an elevator from A to B. The price for 1 trip is as follows:

1) If only one person - height in cents - if 180 -> 180 cents

2) If more than one person -> height of the maximum: [180, 150, 185] -> 185 cents total.

The limit of the elevator is N kg bigger or equal to 700 - for example **700kg.**

You have N clients with kg and height, for example:

**[{h: 180, w: 70}, {h: 180, w: 60},...]**

The task is to calculate the minimum cost to transport all the clients from A to B.

**My solution so far:**

I get the available combinations.

If i have 5 clients: [1], [2]..[5], [1,2], [2,3]...[1,2,3]...,[1,2,3,4,5]

Now the problem is that i have 255 combinations (for N people).

I thought i could get all the combinations calculate the min price, check if kgs in each trip not exceed the max kg capacity and return it like this:

Each nested array are people in one trip

[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]] - each person in separate trip
[[1], [2,3,4,5] - one combination

[[1], [2], [3,4,5]] - second 
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]

Then calculate each row and from then its easy - sort and return the first one.

For 5 clients this works ok, but for 20 the combinations are huge and unavailable to calculate in acceptable time.

Can you help me with directions or full solution how to solve the task.

Thank you:)

Comment: To start I think the problem needs to be more clear. For your very first two bullets... do you mean: (1) "The price for 1 person is 1 cent per centimeter of their height up to a maximum of 180cents" (2) "If more than 1 person, the price is set to match the height of the tallest person"?  (finally, if so, if there are 3 people riding, is the price say 185cents for the trip, OR 185cents per person (e.g. 3*185=555cents))?

Comment: The price for 1 is his cm in cents: 180 -> 180cents. If more than 1 client total price of the trip is the tallest person: [180, 150, 185] - the total price of the trip is 185 cents.

Comment: Do you also have the full data set for the number of clients that are taking this trip? and... I don't think the solution will be to determine all the possible combinations, it will be to maximize the efficiency of each trip so that you make the fewest trips. e.g. plan your very first trip to max out the elevator capacity without exceeding the weight limit... then repeat your logic for the remaining rides

Comment: I have 20 clients with random h (150-200) and w (50-150kg) : [{h: 190, w: 80}, {h: 180, w: 65}....]

Comment: If i maximixe the trip next trips could not be optimized, so the first is ok but there should be 2 more for example. And there can be solution with only 2 trips.

Comment: You can use dijkstra, where each state is which persons are left. You can transition from X to Y if Y is a subset of X and you can do in 1 trip the people that are in X but not in Y. As there are 20 clients, there are 2^20 possible states, should be doable to run in reasonable time

Comment: But they are much more combinations. There can be bilions of combinations. How dijkstra can help me. There can be 20 trips 19 trips 1 trip and with all people combined there are many combinations

Comment: Amount of trips doesn't matter, you are just minimizing cost which is the sum of edge costs between states. And dijkstra only visits each state once

Comment: Can you provide some js code or pseudo code. Number of combinations is very large

Comment: Give me a test case with 20 users

Comment: I have for 3:N=3, max kg 200 clients: 170,90 160,80 150,100. The first is height. The result is 320

Comment: Could you please explain how we get 320 as a result for `N=3, max kg 200 clients: 170,90 160,80 150,100`? I don't understand how.

Comment: trip: [[170,90],[160,80] - price 170 cents
trip 2: [[150,100]] - price 150, total 170 + 150 = 320

Comment: Oh, oops, I forgot about the distinction between height and weight, lol, tx!

Comment: Any update? Did you check my answer?

Comment: Yes im trying to convert it to js but i dont understand how neighours work and why you need distance thanks

Comment: @user2693928 added a js implementation. Remember that if you don´t tag me in comments, I don´t find out you answered me. Neighbors just takes the set of people that still need to go to the floor and generates all possible subsets (a trip) in an efficient way. Distance is needed because distance is the cost, and you want to minimize the cost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dijkstra, where each state is which persons are left. We can use a bitmask to represent the persons that still need to go to the desired floor, a 1 in the ith position means the ith person already went to the desired floor.

A transition means doing a trip with a set of people that still need to go to the desired floor, thus changing the state to have a 1 in the ith position for every person that went in that trip. As there are 20 clients, there are 2^20 possible states. Here is the dijkstra solution I proposed in c++, supports up to 20 persons.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

struct Person {
    int weigth;
    int height;

    Person (int w, int h) {
        weigth = w;
        height = h;
    }
};

set<pair<int, int> > s;
int maxWeigth = 200;
vector<Person> persons;
int distances[1 << 21];
int currentCost;

void visitNeighbors(vector<int>& remainingPersons, int state, int weigthSum, int maxHeight, int index) {
    if (weigthSum > maxWeigth) return;

    if (index != 0) {
        if (distances[state] == -1 || currentCost + maxHeight < distances[state]) {
            distances[state] = currentCost + maxHeight;
            s.insert(make_pair(distances[state], state));
        }
    }

    if (index == remainingPersons.size()) return;

    visitNeighbors(remainingPersons, state | (1 << remainingPersons[index]), weigthSum + persons[index].weigth, max(maxHeight, persons[index].height), index + 1);
    visitNeighbors(remainingPersons, state, weigthSum, maxHeight, index + 1);
}

int main () {
    persons.push_back(Person(90, 170));
    persons.push_back(Person(80, 160));
    persons.push_back(Person(100, 150));

    fill(distances, distances + (1 << 21), -1);

    int target = (1 << (persons.size())) - 1; // 111 means the 3 persons have already arrived at desired floor

    s.insert(make_pair(0, 0)); // initial state is with 0 cost and no person on the desired floor
    distances[0] = 0;

    while (!s.empty()) {
        pair<int, int> p = *s.begin();
        s.erase(s.begin());

        currentCost = p.first;
        int state = p.second;

        vector<int> remainingPersons;


        if (distances[state] != -1 && distances[state] < currentCost) continue;
        if (state == target) break;


        for (int i = 0; i < persons.size(); i++) {
            if ((state & (1 << i)) == 0) { // if we have a 0 at index i on state as a binary string, we still need to move that person
                remainingPersons.push_back(i);
            }
        }

        visitNeighbors(remainingPersons, state, 0, 0, 0);       
    }

    cout << distances[target] << endl;

}
```

**JS Implementation:**

```js
var maxWeigth = 200;

var persons = [{
 height: 170,
  weigth: 90
}, 
{
 height: 160,
  weigth: 80
},
{
 height: 150,
  weigth: 100
}];

var distances = new Array(1 << persons.length);
distances.fill(-1);

var currentCost;

var target = (1 << persons.length) - 1;

var queue = new PriorityQueue({ comparator: (a, b) => a.cost - b.cost});

queue.queue({cost: 0, mask: 0});
distances[0] = 0;

while(queue.length) {
 var state = queue.dequeue();
  
  if (distances[state.mask] != -1 && distances[state.mask] < state.cost) continue;
  if (state.mask == target) break;
  
  var remainingPersons = []
  currentCost = state.cost;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
    if ((state.mask & (1 << i)) == 0) { 
      remainingPersons.push(i);
    }
  }

  visitNeighbors(remainingPersons, state.mask, 0, 0, 0);
}

console.log(distances[target])


function visitNeighbors(remainingPersons, mask, weigthSum, maxHeight, index) {
    if (weigthSum > maxWeigth) return;

    if (index != 0) {
        if (distances[mask] == -1 || currentCost + maxHeight < distances[mask]) {
            distances[mask] = currentCost + maxHeight;
            queue.queue({cost: distances[mask], mask: mask});
        }
    }

    if (index == remainingPersons.length) return;

    visitNeighbors(remainingPersons, mask | (1 << remainingPersons[index]), weigthSum + persons[index].weigth, Math.max(maxHeight, persons[index].height), index + 1);
    visitNeighbors(remainingPersons, mask, weigthSum, maxHeight, index + 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/adamhooper/js-priority-queue/master/priority-queue.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Might be nice to have some words in your answer, explaining how the problem is being modeled.

Comment: @גלעדברקן added

Comment: This is an answer but it is clearly not optimal - it's a greedy solution to a knapsack problem. The actual search space, for the optimal solution is not "people on floor A, people on floor B". It is number of partitions of the set of people, which for 20 people is *way* more than 2^20.

Comment: @spinkus can you come up with a example where real solution is different from my output?

Comment: Well, your code just prints a number not a solution so it's hard to tell exactly what it's doing at glance.

Comment: @spinkus in knapsack you want to maximize profit, here we want to minimize. As for the actual search space, you have a lot of repeated states there. Doing a trip with person 1 and then one with 2,3 is the same as doing 1 with 2,3 and then with 1. Doing a trip with 2 and then with 1,3 is true that the cost will be different, but with dijkstra I am minimizing the cost to reach that state where 1,2 and 3 went to the desired floor